# git merge default commit message now showing

Tags: git, github, merge, commit

I have two repositories in GitHub (let's say repo A and repo B). Assuming both repos have main and dev branch, when I conduct `git merge dev` from main branch in repo A, It shows default commit message such as `Merge branch 'dev'`, whereas in repo B, It does not show such default commit message.

What do I need to do to configure in repo B to display default commit message during merge?

I tried to identify differences in settings between two repos in GitHub.

Comment: Is one of the merges a fast-forward? (i.e. does it create a merge _commit_?). There's too little information in the question for it to be answerable. Important points: what is the history? Have dev and master diverged? What exact commands were used? What is the Git config, especially the `ff` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation, the root cause was the fast-forward.

I have disabled it using `git config --global --add merge.ff false`.